# Help building array hierarchically with taxonomies (to get posts)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

What I need to do is to :

-+ Retrieve all terms assigned to a page
-+ Get all posts assigned to each term
-+ Organize the output in the hierarchic way as in the admin

I'm OK with the first two items, but I cannot seems to find a way to organize my output in the correct hierarchical manner (probably because i'm not good with arrays and probably PHP in general).

This is what I got for now :

```
public function return_all_tax_objects() {

    $obj_term_posts = array();

    foreach ( $this->return_object_terms() as $obj_term ) {

        if ( $obj_term->parent ) {
            unset( $key );
            $ancestors = array_reverse( get_ancestors( $obj_term->term_id, $obj_term->taxonomy ) );
            foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
                $ancestor_term = get_term( $ancestor, $obj_term->taxonomy );
                $key .= "[$ancestor_term->slug]";
            }
            $key .= "[$obj_term->slug]";
        }

        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $obj_term_posts ) ) {

             $get_term_posts = $this->get_posts_for_term( $obj_term );
             array_push ( $obj_term_posts[ $key ], $this->get_posts_for_term( $obj_term ) );

        } else {

            $obj_term_posts[ $key ] = $this->get_posts_for_term( $obj_term );

        }

    }
    return $obj_term_posts;
}
```

And `$this->return_object_terms()` corresponds to a function to returns all terms for a `ID` for all Custom Post Types I have set up, in a flat array :

```
public function return_object_terms() {

    return wp_get_object_terms( $this->object_id, $this->return_object_taxonomies(), array ( 'orderby' => 'term_id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all' ) );
}
```

As you will see in my snapshot for the returned values, I'm close, but :

**Edit :** Changed code for a better option. Still, not working.

Somehow, I got it all but mixed up. I have the correct posts, but I'm not updating the correct index somwhere.

Essentially, what I need is a way to nest child terms into parent term, so I could structure my output :

```
-+ Direction générale des services
--+ (posts)
---+ Services Techniques
---+ (posts)
----+ Directeur des Services Techniques
----+ (posts)
---+ Services Administratifs
---+ (posts)
...
```

[image: Firebug capture of returned array $obj_term_posts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it !

This is the final code that returns a hierarchical array based on taxonomy.

```
public function return_all_tax_objects() {

    $obj_term_posts = array();

            // GET FLAT LIST OF TERMS BELONGING TO THE POST
    foreach ( $this->return_object_terms() as $obj_term ) {

                    // IF TERM HAS A PARENT
        if ( $obj_term->parent ) {
            unset ( $keys );
                            // GET ANCESTORS OF TERM AND REVERSE IT 
                            // SO WE HAVE IT FROM ROOT
            $ancestors = array_reverse( get_ancestors( $obj_term->term_id, $obj_term->taxonomy ) );
                            // WE GET ANCESTORS AND STORE SLUG IN ARRAY
            foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
                $ancestor_term = get_term( $ancestor, $obj_term->taxonomy );
                $keys[] = $ancestor_term->slug;
            }
        }

                    // LAST ITEM FOR KEYS IS CURRENT TERM SLUG
        $keys[] = $obj_term->slug;

                    // DUPLICATE WITH INCLUSION 
        $temp =& $obj_term_posts;

                    // CREATE INDEX FROM KEYS ARRAY
        foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
            $temp =& $temp[ $key ];
        }
        // GET ASSOCIATED POSTS TO THAT TERM 
        $temp = $this->get_posts_for_term( $obj_term );

    }

    return $obj_term_posts;
}
```

Result : 
[image]